# Online self-hosted price list/table solution

Tags: gratis, open-source, web-apps, self-hosted

I am asking for a recommendation on a self-hosted web-based price list/table solution.

On a back-end, it should allow me to quickly make a list of 500+ product names, with a separate price field.

On a front-end, a user would look at that list and enter a quantity of items next to a product name. A user would then hit “Submit” and an order will be emailed to a predetermined address.

So far, I have tried WordPress based Gravity Forms. Technically it allows to do all that, BUT dragging and dropping a product field one-by-one for 500+ items is insane. And even if I do enter all that data, managing such a list would be tedious as well. Gravity Forms is just not designed for this particular task.

Please look at the screenshot of Gravity Forms—it's too cumbersome for large lists:

[image: Gravity Forms]

Now look, for example, at an Excel table—it's compact, fast, easy:

[image]

Is there something like that out there?

Comment: Does it need to be [gratis] or [open-source]? You can add tags by [edit]ing your quesion

Comment: Preferably open-source, though, I would happily adopt a gratis solution also.

Answer (score 1):

Thus far, I have found a plugin for the WordPress that imports entries from a CSV file into a Gravity Forms form, and I also found a non-WordPress based solution.

In the end, I skipped the above mentioned WordPress plugin on its cost terms, and setup a free [InvoicePlane](https://github.com/InvoicePlane/InvoicePlane) application.

InvoicePlane is certainly not as simple on a front-end as I wanted, and actually there is no back-end and front-end separation, but looking into a future I think that an extra capabilities provided by this application would be beneficial in a long run. And instead of searching for an elusive simpler solution that is apparently in a very short supply, I will instead train a user to make use of the InvoicePlane.

Hope this helps someone.